# How do I avoid a strong reference cycle when I need a strong reference in a closure?

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, weak-references

I currently have a strong reference cycle in my code that in the memory graph looks like:

[image: strong reference cycle]

I have filtered out the possibility that I am missing a [weak self], and I believe that it is another instance that is being captured by the closure shown (closure #3, which appears over and over in leaked SKSpriteNodes relating to my "Circle" class).

I have circles of type Circle captured in closures in various places. For instance:

```
let sprite = circle.sprite!

let changeTextureAction = SKAction.run
    {
        sprite.texture = newTexture

        if circle.bonusCircleType == .bonus4 || circle.bonusCircleType == .bonus2x
        {
            let oldArrowSprite1 = sprite.childNode(withName: "arrowSprite1")
            oldArrowSprite1?.removeFromParent()

            let oldArrowSprite2 = sprite.childNode(withName: "arrowSprite2")
            oldArrowSprite2?.removeFromParent()

            let (arrowSprite1, arrowSprite2) = getArrowSprites(circle)
            sprite.addChild(arrowSprite1)
            sprite.addChild(arrowSprite2)
            sprite.removeAction(forKey: "animateCircle")
        }

        else if circle.bonusCircleType == .bomb
        {
            let bombLeftEmitter = sprite.childNode(withName: "bombLeftEmitter")
            bombLeftEmitter?.isPaused = false

            let bombRightEmitter = sprite.childNode(withName: "bombRightEmitter")
            bombRightEmitter?.isPaused = false

            let bombTopEmitter = sprite.childNode(withName: "bombTopEmitter")
            bombTopEmitter?.isPaused = false
        }
    }

        sprite.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: time), SKAction.group([changeTextureAction, expandUpAction, Assets.sharedInstance.fxMatch4]), expandDownAction2]), withKey: "animateNewBonusCircle")
```

Is there a nice way for me to avoid the strong capture of circle by the closure without capturing it as unowned or weak? It is possible that the circle could be deallocated prior to this closure, in which case I get a crash (or with a weak-strong dance what I want to happen doesn't happen -- assume I have other functions where I do want to use, say, the circle's position, even though it may have just been removed).

My initial thought was I could substitute another object with the same properties that I could set as weak, but wasn't sure of the syntax to manage this.

Below is a screenshot of my allocations data, if it gives anyone a clue as to what I'm dealing with. I was suspicious of that call to add my map header, and allocations cites it as using 542 mb of memory, but when I deleted it that did not seem to recover me much memory usage. My guess is it was just the first instance in which my asset singleton was called, which contains texture atlases for my game. Now I'm thinking perhaps the atlases themselves are for some reason not being deallocated for some reason, but I actually manually deallocate these in code. Argh. Any thoughts appreciated.

[image]

Comment: _"assume I have other functions where I do want to use, say, the circle's position, even though it may have just been removed"_ From my reading of your description, you're zoomed too far in on the closure capture problem. Your problem seems to actually be further back, in your overall object graph's structure. You need the `Circle`s to stay alive; therefore something needs to be their owner. Identify that object and fix the problem there.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I am seeing memory retain cycles in my dreams, so you may be right. Let me take a fresh look from that perspective, and I will follow up.

Comment: Here is what I've come up with: after running allocations, I determined that a header that I add in both my map screen and in my game scene is using ~542 mb of memory. It has objects on it (CountingLabels, which are labels that count up rank, coins, lives values), which I believe are leaking. However, the absolute value of that memory usage seems crazy to me. The header itself is 1242x391 pixels, 24-bit color depth, so ~1.5 mb of memory usage. Any thoughts?

Comment: I will also add my Allocations data. I have only used these tools for a few weeks, so any guiding thoughts would be much appreciated.